# Cannot make ghostscript work on moodle 3.9

Tags: php, pdf, moodle, ghostscript

Ghostscript is installed, permissions are ok, and pathtogs is correct (shows green tick on server/system paths). But when I test the Ghostscript path I get:

```
Error generating image with ghostscript, debugging info:  
Command:  -q -sDEVICE=png16m -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r -dFirstPage= -dLastPage= -dDOINTERPOLATE -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile= 
    
Result:
    
    
Output:
```

Which doesn't even show gs on command line. It looks as if the variable containing the path to gs was empty. Any clues?

Thanks in advance